# Which XEN IOMMU features are min needed for VGA passthru?

Tags: vga, xen

To run HVM (Hardware-assisted virtualization) the CPU must support this by having IO-MMU feature (Intel calls this VT-X). I have an **Intel Core 2 Quad Q8400 CPU** which support the virutalization Vt-X(see here: http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology) technology, but not the Intel® EPT technology.

My question is the EPT technology needed to get VGA passthru to work?

In terms of `xl dmesg | grep HVM` what resamples the EPT techology?

Answer (score 0):

First of all IOMMU is not VT-X or AMD-V or EPT for that matter which are CPU virtualisation extensions and MMU technology but using CPU.

For advanced DMA devices such as graphics card your motherboard and CPU must have IOMMU support - a peace of hardware that manages translation from host to guest os.

You will find this technology in Intel and AMD server grade boards, and if you are on a budget Gigabyte AMD970/990 boards support this. This is however not advertised and you must go through MB manual to find out if it supports it. If it does you simply enable it in BIOS. I think there is Wikipedia article that keeps track of IOMMU capable hardware.

I am using Gigabyte GA990FX UD3 with AMD FX8120 with ESXi to pass network cards down to guests and it works just fine, but wit graphics card you will probably have some performance drop.

You will also need to make sure that you do not pass your only GPU down to guest, as this will render your host inoperable  so having two graphics cards is a must.

Comment: supposedly nvidia GPUs don't do passthrough - so you'd probably want to use a AMD GPU here